# Boolean expressions is not coming as expected after query parsing Lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have the below code. I am expecting to see the exact query, including binary expressions, after parsing but the output is not what I expected.

```
StandardQueryParser parser = new StandardQueryParser(new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query = parser.parse("siteName:center OR siteProfileHeader:center ", "");
System.out.println(query.toString());
```

output:

> siteName:center siteProfileHeader:center"

expected output:

> siteName:center OR siteProfileHeader:center"

---

```
StandardQueryParser parser = new StandardQueryParser(new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query = parser.parse("siteName:center AND siteProfileHeader:center ", "");
System.out.println(query.toString());
```

output:

> +siteName:center +siteProfileHeader:center

Comment: The two query expressions, in both cases, are equivalent.

Comment: what i am saying here is AND is replacing by + sign. I want the parsing value to say AND

Comment: Query.parse shows you a string representing the query, which is similar to queryparser syntax (though not necessarily parse-able). There is no guarantee that it will be the exact same string you passed into the queryparser to get the query (in this case, that would be acceptable, but in most cases it wouldn't). I mean, you *do* already have that string, though...